# Javascript need to set the field delimiter for tsv output file when opened in excel

Tags: javascript

I am outputting to a tsv file headers and then their fields.

each field is separated by a tab. when opened in notepad the output looks good
but when opening in excel the everything is in one column, but I want the two fields to be in separate column.

how can I set the delimiter for when opened by excel so they are separate column?

this is the tsv opened
[TSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF3iH.png)
this is the excel opened
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKyBC.png)

this is my code so far

```
try{

    const tsvString = [
        [
          "header1",
          "header2"
        ],
        ...kvObjs.map(item => [
          item.field1,
          item.fiedl2
        ])
      ]
      .map(e => e.join("\t"))
          .join("\n");

    var tsvContent = "\ufeff"+tsvString;


   fs.writeFileSync("/document/outputDoc.tsv", tsvContent);

   } catch (err){
        winston.error(`Error outputDocFile :: ${err}`);
   }
```

Comment: You can try with a semicolong (;) as divider - excel seems to like that more. You can also try to use the File->Import-function to open the tab-divided tsv.